# TypeScript in createContext issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, typing

On my app I have this:

```
const restaurantsArr = [{ name: McDonald, rating: 5 }]
const RestaurantContext = createContext();
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantsArr);
```

For `Provider`, I want to pass my destructured variables from `useState`.

```
<Provider value={[restaurants, setRestaurants]} />
```

TS yelling at me, that `createContext` must have value, but if my `createContext` has empty array for example I have errors.

How I should create interface `ContextProps`?

In fact, I have array which contains another array of objects and a function.

I'm fighting with this for a couple of hours and I have warnings and errors all the time...

Comment: What is the issue here? Have you attempted to create the interface?

Comment: I have problem with creating proper interfeace for ContextProps

Comment: You need to show effort on solving the problem. What did you come up with?

Comment: interface ContextProps {
    restaurants: {
name: String; 
rating: Number; 
description: String;
}[];
    setRestaurants: () => void;
}

export const RestaurantsContext = createContext<ContextProps[]>([]);


But it doesn't work...

Comment: You need a default value for your context, reference: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24509#issuecomment-382213106 but because this can be awkward at times, refer to https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively for a good approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have this now:

```
export const RestaurantsContext = createContext<any>([]);

interface Props {
    children: ReactElement;
}

const RestaurantsProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantsArr)

   return (
      <RestaurantsContext.Provider value={[restaurants, setRestaurants]}>
         {children}
      </RestaurantsContext.Provider>
    )
```

But It's just walk-around with any on export `const RestaurantsContext = createContext<any>([])`.

What I want to do is to have something like:

```
interface ContextProps {
   //and something here
}
```

But how should I type [data, setData] ? It's an array with array of objects and with setState function.